# Where can I find a comprehensive list of Fedora17 hotkeys?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, fedora, hotkeys

I'm very new to Linux and just downloaded F17 onto my box. I'm used to running Win7 and having tons of desktop hotkeys and shortcuts. I know that some of these quick tricks must exist in the Fedora environment, but I'm not sure where they are/how to configure them.

Do I have to yum install some sort of hotkey package? Any advice or tips is MUCH appreciated.

Comment: Distros don't have hotkeys, DEs have hotkeys.

Comment: By DE do you mean Desktop Environment?

Comment: Hotkeys will depend on the desktop environment such as KDE or Gnome.  Which one are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using Gnome. version 3 I believe.